# Use two variable in awk, to select lines based on field values

Tags: awk

I have a file (sample.bedgraph) with lines looks like:

```
8   43825627    43825628    1313
X   1753769 1753780 14
```

I would like to get rid of any line that has field 4 less than 10 and great than 150 -- the filtered file should only have the 2nd line. I know I can simply do:

```
awk '$4 >= 10 && $4 <= 150' sample.bedgraph > sample.filtered.bedgraph
```

However, my 10 and 150 threshold come from some upstream pipe command, and I would need to refer to them as $Min and $Max, so if I do:

```
awk '$4 >= $Min && $4 <= $Max' sample.bedgraph > sample.filtered.bedgraph
```

It has no return at all. And if I add "'" to my variables ($Min and $Max), it 
 will not filter any line away. If I only compare to the min or max, it does not work. I have check some other posts and people suggest "-v", but I had no luck with it either.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose if you got shell variables like

```
$ Min=10
$ Max=150
```

in awk you can use like below, if 4th field in a record/row/line, lies between 10 and 150, such record will be printed.

```
$ awk -v min="$Min" -v max="$Max" '$4 >= min && $4 <= max' sample.bedgraph > sample.filtered.bedgraph
```

> I would like to get rid of any line that has field 4 less than 10 and
>   great than 150 -- the filtered file should only have the 2nd line. I
>   know I can simply do:

field4 less than 10 and greater than 150 is not possible together using `AND`, so you can have `OR` like below :

```
awk '$4 < 10 || $4 >150 {next}1' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
8   43825627    43825628    1313
X   1753769 1753780 14

$ awk '$4 < 10 || $4 >150 {next}1' infile
X   1753769 1753780 14
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Could you please explain a little bit on {next}?

Comment: If field4 is less than 10 or greater than 150 , we are not printing record. next means go to next row/record. `1` at the end is nothing but `{print $0}`

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much what [@3161993](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46940147/4162356) said but you *could* use double quotes (`"`) for the awk and let shell expand the `$Var`s. It is looking for trouble (lotsa escaping) but here it goes:

```
$ awk "\$4 >= $Min && \$4 <= $Max" file
X   1753769 1753780 14
```

Comment: Thank you. What makes you say this will have trouble? Would you recommend -v instead?

Comment: Yes I would. Using `-v` method saves you from the trouble of escaping every `$` and some other characters as well and leaves the code more readable.